# Global vs local variable efficiency in multiple function call

Tags: python, loops, numpy

First caveat I understand that premature optimization is always bad.
Second caveat I'm fairly new to python.

I'm reading in many million data chunks. Each chunk consists of 64 bits and is held in a numpy array. In order to do bit operations on a numpy.uint64 type the desired bit shift quantity must also be of the same type:numpy.uint64.

This can be accomplished by either casting the number or making a variable.

```
number1 = numpy.uint64(80000)
shift_amount = numpy.uint64(8)
#option 1
number1 >> numpy.uint64(8)
#option2
number1 >> shift_amount
```

looping  10000 times and checking how long it took. Option2 always wins out I'm assuming because the overhead of creating a numpy integer is done only once.

My current program calls a function for each chunk of data a processes the raw bits. This function is called millions of times and appends a few different lists. Assuming the same idea and just using globally defined values for the shift/bit operations two more loop conditions were tested.

```
def using_global(number1):
    global shift_amount
    number1 >> shift_amount

def using_local(number1):
    shift = np.uint64(54)
    number1 >> shift
```

looping these 10000 times the function using global was always an order of magnitude faster. **Question:** Is it bad practice to have a bunch(10+) global variables? https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips states that local variable will be faster. In this instance I found that not to be the case. My main loop simply calls the function for each word in the million of data words so that's probably inefficient too.

Comment: You don't need `global` to read from a global, just to write it. I don't think it's a bad idea for constants if you name the variables appropriately.

Comment: The fundamental difference is you are only creating the int in the local function, creating the it takes about 80 percent of the total time in the function so of course it is a lot slower

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks for the response that clears up a lot of things actually. I will continue to read from global variables in this case it seems the most efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not made for massive number operations. Numpy instead is. Put all data junks in one numpy array. This is way faster than using loops and single function calls:

```
values = numpy.ndarray(1000000, dtype=numpy.uint64)
# fill in the data
values >>= 8
```

If you're shift depends on the highest nibble, for example, the nibble-values from 0 to 15 have a lookup table for the shift:

```
shift_by_nibble = numpy.array([8,16,24,30,34,60,50,40,44,48,52,56,62,4,12,20], dtype=numpy.uint8)
values >>= shift_by_nibble[values>>60]
```

Comment: interesting insight although each chunk needs to be shifted different amount based on the top nibble.

Comment: please show how the real shift is calculated. You probably can vectorize this too.

Comment: each element gets multiple bit operations based on the upper nibble. Then if the nibble matches conditions further bit operations are performed and their values stored in a list. The code is too long to add in a comment and it would appear you can't send a message through this site.

Comment: @kaminsknator: see my example, this gives you perhaps an idea how to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

`using_global` references a global variable. `using_local` references a local variable, but it also includes a call to `np.uint64()`, which affects performance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue, another valid option would be to pass the variable `shift_amount` into the function as:

```
def my_func(number1, shift_amount):
    return number1 >> shift_amount
```

and then calling the function as `new_number = my_func(old_number, shift_amount)`

Comment: a good alternative though passing a function 10+ parameters seemed like a mess. Testing that method out it was only slightly slower than reading the global variable. Still much faster that explicitly declaring a local variable. Thanks.